# Change label text color RadioButton

Tags: c#, colors, radio-button, label

My first assignment is to create a program that can dynamically change the text color, alignment etc of a string a user has entered in a text box. Here's my problem: first of all my bold and underline button work, but not the italic one:

```
label5.Font = new Font(label5.Font.Name, label5.Font.Size, label5.Font.Style ^ FontStyle.Italic);
```

Secondly, I Have to use Radiobuttons to change my text color, and have managed to do this button per button but I wanted to make it more efficient by making a single procedure that would use my radiobutton's name to change the font, here's what I mean:

```
protected void Colorchange(object sender, EventArgs e)    
{        
    RadioButton selectedRadioButton = (RadioButton)sender;        
    selectedRadioButton.Name = sender.ToString();

    label5.ForeColor = Color.???????; <---Can't figure how to put the name string here....
}
```

Comment: Static Color class has properties by color names so Color.Red; will do for example

Answer (score 2):

Changed, due your comment:

```
label5.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
//or other option:
label5.Style.Add("color", "Red");
```

change italic:

```
label5.Font.Italic = true;
//or other option
label5.Style.Add("font-style", "italic");
```

the second option in case you want to pass string as you described.

Comment: That's what i did the first time, what i want to do now is name my radiobutton "Red" for example and then use that string in the color change

Comment: if you want to use string to change the color, try the other alternative I just edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you search is:

```
Color red = Color.FromName("Red");

Color blue = Color.FromName(label5.Name);
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the color of text in `TextBox` use following code

```
    textBox1.ForeColor=System.Drawing.Color.Green //  or choose any color from dropdown
```

You can do same fo label.

```
    label5.ForeColor=System.Drawing.Color.Red //  or  any color
```